# rest - RESTEasy cutting trailing slash off @Path

Tags: rest, jax-rs, resteasy

RESTEasy looks to ignore the trailing slash, so I cannot write two different web services with and without an trailing slash, and this example shows:

```
@Path("foo")
public class TestClass {

    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    public Response bar1() {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/bar/")
    public Response bar2() {
        ...
    }
}
```

With RESTEasy the GET-request to /foo/bar as well as /foo/bar/ are handled by bar2(). Considering RFC3986 and the JAX-RS Spec I do not see why this is handled like this. Could this be a problem with RESTEasy or is there something I oversee?

Comment: Another strange effect I see is that if you have only your method with @Path("/bar") both urls /root/bar and /root/bar/ will trig that method... the probelm is how to treat the relatives urls after if we do not know if it was called with a trailing / or not.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxrs-1.0-final-spec.pdf) says

**3.7 Matching Requests to Resource Methods**

**3.7.3 Converting URI Templates to Regular Expressions**

> 1. URI encode the template, ignoring URI template variable specifications.
> 2. Escape any regular expression characters in the URI template, again ignoring URI template variable specifications.
> 3. Replace each URI template variable with a capturing group containing the specified regular expression or ‘([^/]+?)’ if no
>      regular expression is specified.
> 4. **If the resulting string ends with ‘/’ then remove the final character**.
> 5. Append ‘(/.*)?’ to the result.

As I read it, the RESTEasy implements the spec correctly.

Comment: What is strange is that the context is not the same if you need to put a relative link. if you put the trailing slash it does trig the same method (that is ok for me) but the <a> link contains something like root/path1/path1/xyz instead root/path1/xyz. How to know if the original url contained the trailing slash ?

Comment: I stumbled upon this behavior recently, and I'm choked that people like Roy Fielding, Jan Algermissen or Julian Reschke could have let something like this go into the spec. You have to get injected a `@Context UriInfo` and then check `uriInfo.getPath().endsWith("/")` before you can safely use relative URI references.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Roy Fielding was not involved in the creation of the JAX-RS spec. This hideous mess was designed by someone else.

Comment: @gili His name is listed as part of the spec authors. See also https://twitter.com/fielding/status/483677900244516865